# set up web app contents based on location in php

Tags: php, html, mysql, url

I have a website for online shopping in php.

```
example.com
```

I tried many ideas.its not worked.
Now i need to add admin part for adding location. If I add Madras as location, Shopping items for Madras should show.

Please give the logic for adding admin part.
If I add 'Madras' as location. URL should be

```
madras.example.com
```

and it should show contents available for madras.

Please help me in building admin part. I am stuck now.

Comment: first, tell us **what online shopping script/software** that you're currently using? secondly, we do not have any idea about "adding admin" part. please refine your question

Comment: i need to create sub domain based on location.If i add 'Madras' as location.URL should be

madras.example.com

Answer (score 0):

Actually you can use $_GET variables but it is not secured at all .
You have to use $_SESSION variables 
This link may help in many php things
  [This link may help you](http://openclassrooms.com/courses/concevez-votre-site-web-avec-php-et-mysql/variables-superglobales-sessions-et-cookies) 
look for the $_SESSION Part